# Query with date condition in where clause returns no rows but works in SQL Developer

Tags: vb.net, oracle

Thanks in advance if anyone can help... this is driving me crazy!

I have a query like

```
select * from tranHistory where itemid = 10 and created_dttm >= '21-Feb-2012';
```

Simple, right?  Run from vb.net it returns no rows.  Run from SQL Developer it returns 99 rows.  I originally thought it was a parameter problem as the query used to look like

```
select * from tranHistory where itemid = 10 and created_dttm >= :tranHistoryDate;
```

In the original query there were two other parameters and I verified they were in the right order.  I simplified it to this form to eliminate as many variables as possible.  We're using Oracle 11g, Visual Studio 2010, and Oracle ODP.Net for the data provider.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this fails!

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is to the same database that SQL developer connects to?  Are you sure the date format being put into the "String" is in the same NLS format as the database is expecting (perhaps an explicit format data is needed?) in .net is the connection object reporting an error that is being ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate connection problems, if you remove the restriction on date from the `WHERE` clause, does it return any data in vb.net?

If so, it's most likely a date string parsing issue. Check the NLS settings on the server, or try using a language agnostic date format like this:

```
and created_dttm >= TO_DATE('20120221', 'YYYYMMDD');
```

If removing the date results in no data being returned, it is almost certainly not a problem with your query, but a problem with the connection to the database. Is it connecting to the same  schema as from SQL Developer?

Comment: Argggh!  (slaps head!)  I hate it when I outsmart myself!  There was no problem with the query, it was the data.  I developed the query against day old production data and forgot my development environment is out of date.  I increased the age of the dateFrom parameter and it's working.  Thanks!  I should know better!

Answer (score 1):

Using  `>= date'2013-02-21'`  works in SQL DEV and your code ? If so, you have problem with implicit char to date conversion- which depends on your session settings...